# Measure of the Base of an Isoceles Triangle

Tags: geometry

How would you find the length of the base of an isoceles triangle if the only info you have is that each leg of the triangle is 11?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on other parameters. You can touch two $11$ unit line segments and vary the angle between them. Every angle would produce a different length of third side. You can write it as a function of angle $\theta$ as :

$$\text{base}^2=2\cdot11^2(1-\cos\theta)$$

Answer (score 0):

If the length of leg $AB$ and the length of leg $AC$ are $11$, then the distance from $B$ to $C$ cannot be more the $11+11=22$, since "The shortest distance between two points (in this case $B$ and $C$) is a straight line."  But the distance from $B$ to $C$ can be anything that is less than $22$ and more than $0$.

Comment: The distance $BC$ can be anything that is less than $22$ and greater than or equal to $11$ as well, though.

Comment: Sorry, typo: I meant $22$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't! Imagine you've got a straight line of length 11 already drawn. Now you can draw (pretty much) any other straight line you like starting at one of the ends of the first line you had. These can then be the two legs of an isosceles triangle.

You can be certain though that the base isn't longer than 22!